# How to Highlight Text on Webpage in Microsoft Edge with Console

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm attempting to write a line of code that an end-user can type into Edge console to highlight an unchanging list of words in their browser. I've tried every multi-search Edge addon that I could find in the extension store and none of them work on the specific website that my end-users are using.
All I need is for every instance of specific words to be highlighted at the same time, preferably all at once (eg., "and", "this", "that")
I'm unfamiliar with the Edge console language and have not been able to find much documentation on this exact topic, but this is my non-working code I have so far:

```
i = document.body.innerText.matchAll("and");
for (each m in i) {m.style.border('1px solid lime')};
```

I've also tried modifying `$$('a').forEach(a => a.style.border='1px solid lime')` to find text to no avail.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **regular expression** for matching text, and here's an example for you to highlight all "and" text at once.

```
var content = document.body.innerHTML;
var s = "and";
var reg = new RegExp("\\b("+s+")\\b", "g");
var str = content;
var newstr = str.replace(reg, "<span style='border: 1px solid lime'>$1</span>");
document.body.innerHTML = newstr
```